# Maatwebsite excel import return 2 new eloquents problem

Tags: laravel, eloquent, maatwebsite-excel

I tried to make an import command using maatwebsite/excel, and in the process, i need two make two new eloquents model, with the default function from maatwebsite import how can i achieve that?

so far i've been doing this

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    return 
    new Siswa([
       'created_at'     => $row[1],
       'updated_at'    => $row[2], 
       'nis' => $row[3],
       'user_id'     => $row[4],
       'nama'    => $row[5], 
       'nik' => $row[6],
       'alamat'     => $row[7],
       'ayah'    => $row[8], 
       'ibu' => $row[9],
       'email'     => $row[10],
       'kerja_ayah'    => $row[11], 
       'kerja_ibu' => $row[12],
       'wali'    => $row[13], 
       'kerja_wali' => $row[14],
       'telpon_ayah'     => $row[15],
       'telpon_ibu'    => $row[16], 
       'kelas' => $row[17],
       'referensi'     => $row[18],
       'note'    => $row[19], 
       'channel' => $row[20],
       'url_foto' => $row[21],
       'outlet'    => $row[22], 
       'penilaian1' => $row[23],
       'penilaian2'     => $row[24],
       'penilaian3'    => $row[25], 
       'penilaian4' => $row[26],
       'penilaian5'     => $row[27],
       'target'    => $row[28], 
       'prodi_id' => $row[29],
    ]);

    new User([
        'name' => $row[5],
        'email' => $row[10],
        'password' => bcrypt($row[3].'*'),
        'outlet_id' => $row[22],
     ]);
    }
    }
```

Here is my controller

```
public function import(Request $request) 
{
    Excel::import(new SiswaImport, $request->file('file'));

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

the only problem is that, its only create the first model without the second, what seems to be the problem? can anone help?

Comment: everything after return is not executed

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you put return before the new User creation, everything after return will not be executed. so here's how you supposed to modify your Import Code:

```
public function model(array $row){
    new Siswa([
        'created_at'     => $row[1],
        'updated_at'    => $row[2], 
        'nis' => $row[3],
        'user_id'     => $row[4],
        'nama'    => $row[5], 
        'nik' => $row[6],
        'alamat'     => $row[7],
        'ayah'    => $row[8], 
        'ibu' => $row[9],
        'email'     => $row[10],
        'kerja_ayah'    => $row[11], 
        'kerja_ibu' => $row[12],
        'wali'    => $row[13], 
        'kerja_wali' => $row[14],
        'telpon_ayah'     => $row[15],
        'telpon_ibu'    => $row[16], 
        'kelas' => $row[17],
        'referensi'     => $row[18],
        'note'    => $row[19], 
        'channel' => $row[20],
        'url_foto' => $row[21],
        'outlet'    => $row[22], 
        'penilaian1' => $row[23],
        'penilaian2'     => $row[24],
        'penilaian3'    => $row[25], 
        'penilaian4' => $row[26],
        'penilaian5'     => $row[27],
        'target'    => $row[28], 
        'prodi_id' => $row[29],
    ]);

    new User([
        'name' => $row[5],
        'email' => $row[10],
        'password' => bcrypt($row[3].'*'),
        'outlet_id' => $row[22],
    ]);

    return 'something';
}
```